# Is there a way to compute Cholesky and SVD for a matrix with an infinite entry?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Do you know is there any way to compute SVD or Cholesky decomposition of a matrix such as $$\begin{pmatrix}1&-\infty \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ or not?

Comment: A matrix with infinite values is squarely outside of the realm of linear algebra.

Comment: how about replacing infinity by a parameter and performing the task. then letting the parameter go to infinity?